# How to check nothing in regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have 3 versions of string:

1. `[center][thumb]http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2010-04/1271272006_tn.jpg[/thumb][/center]`
2. `[center][img]http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2012-01/1325796885.jpg[/img][/center]`
3. `[img]http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2012-01/1325796885.jpg[/img]`

It also can be `[left][/left]` or `[right][/right]`. First two i selected via `/\[(center|left|right)\]\[(img|thumb)\](.*)?\[(\/img|\/thumb)\]\[(\/center|\/left|\/right)\]/`, but with third is one problem: how to check if "previous" just don't exist ?

P.S.
I need to get only url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simpler and less elegant:

```
$str = '[center][img]http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2012-01/1325796885.jpg[/img][/center]';

$url = preg_replace('/.*?(http.+?)\[\/.*+/', "$1", $str);
```

Comment: getting `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '.'`

Comment: Sorry, try now...was missing a `\\`

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.  Note that if your URLs ever contain `[` you will need to rework this a bit.  That's not a typical scenario though (for most applications).

Comment: Wait, why not `'/http[^[]+/'` ?  Same restrictions, easier to read.  Probably more efficient, gets the url (as needed).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove those "tags"?

```
$buffer = strtr($input, array('[' => '<', ']' => '>'));
$url = strip_tags($buffer);
```

See [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strtr) and [`strip_tags`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/strip_tags)

For your three examples this is:

```
http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2010-04/1271272006_tn.jpg
http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2012-01/1325796885.jpg
http://some_domain.com/uploads/posts/2012-01/1325796885.jpg
```

Comment: Would be interested to know if this is more or less efficient than handling with a RegEx.  Regardless, it's soooo clean.

Comment: There's a problem with this approach, `[` and `]` are valid URI characters, are they not?

Comment: quite i nice thing, but i firstly need to get URL, upload it and change with a new link...

Comment: Just did some tests:
1357604711.891 - regex
1357604759.2105 - functions

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove all `[*]` "tags", you can do something like this:

```
$tag_replace_pattern = '#\[.*\]#U'; // note 'U' pattern modifier for ungreedy search
$url = preg_replace($tag_replace_pattern, '', $original_string);
```

If you only need to remove specific patterns you can use this:

```
$tag_replace_pattern = '#\[/?(thumb|left|center|right|img)\]#U';
$url = preg_replace($tag_replace_pattern, '', $original_string);
```